# How to make text start from the left

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got an editable ComboBox, and when text is added which is too long, it appears like this:

[image]

How can I make the textbox start from the beginning of the string?

```
TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
txt.Text = "[Children]";

    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border Name="Border" Padding="1" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**ComboBox:**

```
ComboBox cmbValue1 = new ComboBox();
cmbValue1.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
cmbValue1.IsEditable = true;
cmbValue1.Width = 70;
TextBox txtEdit = (TextBox)((sender as ComboBox).Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", (sender as ComboBox)));
txtEdit.Tag = selection;
```

Comment: You are going to get some (a lot) of flack for not showing what you have tried so far, so that people can help you specifically beyond that which you can google.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - there isnt much code to show

Comment: I believe the problem is with custom styles for combobox, please show XAML theme/styles

Comment: have you used hard Size

Comment: @sll - I don't have a style for ComboBox, however i do have one for textboxes. Just edited my question with code

Comment: Can you also add the TextBox declaration/XAML as well? Will have a play with it.

Comment: @WPF - see my answer, it should do the trick.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - No luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selection start back to 0 in order to make it "left aligned" once the user types something in.

Do this via the `TextBoxBase.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event - here's some XAML:

```
 <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1"
           IsEditable="True" 
           TextBoxBase.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus_1">
```

And the event itself:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus_1(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtEdit = (TextBox)((sender as ComboBox).Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", (sender as ComboBox)));
    txtEdit.SelectionStart = 0;
}
```

I think this should give enough for you to adapt to your application. I tested in an empty WPF app and it works whether you press TAB or click on another part of the UI with the mouse.

**Edit:**

Here's how to add the event in code:

Not sure how your app is structured, but again, this works for me:

```
private void Window_Initialized_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmbValue1 = new ComboBox();
    cmbValue1.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
    cmbValue1.IsEditable = true;
    cmbValue1.Width = 70;
    cmbValue1.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus_1;

    this.MyCanvas.Children.Add(cmbValue1);
}
```

(Using same event handler I posted above in this answer)

**Edit:**

Here is a link to the working project: Note -- it works if the text in editable ComboBox is not selected when you lose focus (i.e., after you type something or just unselect). I'll try and fix that.

```
http://23.23.250.9/wpfresource.zip
```

Comment: No luck :/ It's remaining the same for some reason

Comment: @WPF Please add (by editing the question) any other details you think may be helpful, such as, is the ComboBox in another control or directly on a canvas, etc. I can post my app with just a ComboBox in it and show that this works, so there must be something else interfering. Did the TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus event fire if you put a breakpoint on it?

Comment: The main issue seems to be that I cannot set the TextBoxBase.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus event through code-behind. And sicne the ComboBox is created dynamically, I think that's a must. Could you should how I can set this event from code behind, rather from XAML?

Comment: I had tried that David, however while the event fired, the textbox remained the same

Comment: You've got something else going on, or another event that may be cancelling this out that might be firing afterwards - any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26551/discussion-between-david-khaykin-and-wpf)

Comment: I've tried creating a sample application, but it did not work. Would you like me to send it to you as promised?

Comment: I will zip mine up and post it for you as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @WPF - added project to answer

Comment: Haven't really understood what the sample is supposed to be doing. Is the combobox meant to be empty?

Comment: I posted in the chat, not sure if you're still there but I'll keep the window open. 
In the application, you have an editable ComboBox. Type [children] into it, and you'll see the left side of it disappear because it's too long for the width of the ComboBox. Then click on the other textbox (or press tab) and you will see [children] reset to the left so you see the word from the beginning. Is this not what your issue was in the first place?